# search column name based on matching row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below:

```
A B C D E F Input
1 2 3 4 5 6   1
1 2 3 4 5 6   3
```

I want an output column where I can get the column name, something like below:

```
 A B C D E F Input Output
 1 2 3 4 5 6   1    A
 1 2 3 4 5 6   3    C
```

As you can see above that in row 1, Input has value 1 and column A also has value 1, so the output is A.

Comment: While stack overflow repays efforts from contributors, the asker should also acknowledge the answers, basic courtesy...?

Answer (score 4):

We can do `idxmax`

```
df['Output']=df.drop('Input',1).eq(df.Input,0).idxmax(1)
df['Output']
0    A
1    C
dtype: object
```

Comment: @anky 100% agree ~

Comment: this is great :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with `.dot`:

```
df.drop('Input',1).eq(df['Input'],axis=0).dot(df.columns.difference(['Input']))
```

---

```
0    A
1    C
```